# How to get data as DataSet from stored procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework with asp.net.

I add the my database and stored procedure to the ADO.net entity data model.

I want get data from the stored procedure preprocessed as DataTable. I create the function import.

[image]

and I call it like this

```
DataTable user= db.f_GetbyUser((Guid)User.UserId);
```

But there is error and it says

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult' to 'System.Data.DataSet'

So can you please tell me how can I run the stored procedure and get the data as data set

Comment: EntityFramework is an ORM, i.e. it maps data to strongly typed objects / collections, not DataSets.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147344/dataset-vs-entity-framework-with-stored-procedures) might offer a bit more information

Comment: The whole **point** of EF is to **get away** from using the column/row model of data sets and data table and instead use **proper objects** and collections thereof....

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct conversion. You have to either loop thru result and populated datatable/dataset manually in the loop or use the same connection but in real ADO.NET Command object/Adapter objects to fill Dataset.

But you shouldn't really be needing Datasets in EF Project, if you do use EF - use strong types it generates for you.

Comment: In theory that is correct, but it would be very wrong to actually do that

Comment: It is wrong to use untyped datatable in EF project, you gotta use wrong methods to achieve wrong results :)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing technologies here.  As @yuriy-galanter says, it is technically possible if you hack the data in to a DataSet / DataTable yourself, but you need to reconsider your data access approach and opt for either DataSets, EF (or something even better).

[More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147344/dataset-vs-entity-framework-with-stored-procedures)